# ORDER BY in VIEW returns different results SQL

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2000, sql-order-by

This is my viww:

```
CREATE VIEW [STD_USER].[view_TransInvoice]
AS

SELECT TOP 999999 Customernr, Referensnr,'2' as a, InvoiceRowData, FileHead
    FROM [STD_USER].[Transexport]
    WHERE InvoiceRowData IS NOT NULL
    UNION 
SELECT TOP 999999 Customernr, Referensnr,'1' AS a , InvoiceHead , FileHead
    FROM [STD_USER].[Transexport]
    WHERE InvoiceHead IS NOT NULL
    UNION 
SELECT TOP 999999 Customernr, Referensnr,'3' AS a , InvoiceFoot , FileHead 
    from [STD_USER].[Transexport]
    WHERE InvoiceFoot IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Customernr, Referensnr, 3
```

When I run it on the server (Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition v. 8.00.2055) x64 I get the result that I want in the right order.

But when I run it on (Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition v.10.50.1702.0) x86  I do not get the same result. It’s likes it ignores the ORDER BY statement when I run the VIEW. If I just run the SELECT statements I do on the other hand get the RIGHT result with the right order.
The databases are exactly the same and the scripts as well on both the servers.

Please help me!

Comment: The first 2 branches of your `UNION` will be returning undeterministic results. You need an `ORDER BY` on those too to say `TOP 999999` as ordered by what (except if you have less rows than that and it was only there to try and create a SQL Server 2000 ordered view?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need an `ORDER BY` for the results you need to put an `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` from the view.

The `ORDER BY` inside the View only serves to control what the `TOP` applies to for the `[STD_USER].[Transexport]` branch not for the eventual order of results in select operations against the view.

See [TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx) for more explanation of this.

**Edit** It is quite interesting though that the role of the final `ORDER BY` changes depending upon whether it is in a `View` or not. When the `SELECT` is run outside of a View it serves to order the entire results and it's role in limiting the `TOP` for the final branch of the `UNION` disappears.

**Edit 2** This odd behaviour is discussed in the comments of [this recent Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/719420/unexpected-results-when-using-order-by-fetch-from-in-derived-tables-with-union)

```
CREATE TABLE A (C VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE B (C VARCHAR(100))


SELECT TOP 1000 C 
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1000 C
FROM B
ORDER BY C

GO

CREATE VIEW V
AS
SELECT TOP 1000 C 
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1000 C
FROM B
ORDER BY C

GO

SELECT *
FROM V

GO

DROP TABLE A
DROP TABLE B
DROP VIEW V
```

[image: Plan]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you are supposed to set an `ORDER BY` in the `VIEW` for ordering the data. A view outputs a set of data, which can then be queried.

This should be done when querying the View.

```
SELECT *
FROM [view_TransInvoice]
ORDER BY Customernr, Referensnr, a
```

Comment: You can have `ORDER BY` in a view, if (and only if) there is `TOP` in the related `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not get the hotfix on one of the servers?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926292