# Strange Order By behaviour with Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone explain to me what is happening here. The behavior is not as I expect:

```
select category,timefield from test where category='A'
union
select top 10 category,timefield from test where category='B' order by timefield desc
```

What I want is all rows of category A and only the 10 most recent from category B.
When executed, the results are actually: *All of category A (sorted by timefield descending) + the **first** 10 rows of category B (sorted by timefield descending)*

Stranger still, if we take this whole statement and place it in a subquery, I would expect the behavior to remain the same and evaluated as before, but it is not:

```
select * from (
    select category,timefield from test where category='A'
    union
    select top 10 category,timefield from test where category='B' order by timefield desc
) subq
```

This returns *all of category A (in ascending order) + the 10 most recent of category B (in descending order).*
Which is exactly what I want.

Why does the first statement not produce what I expect and why does the second behave very differently ??

(This is SQL Server 2008)

Comment: A very similar question, where the reason of this behaviour is explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271045/order-by-in-view-returns-different-results-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses in the first query, because the `order by` is applied to the result of the `union`.  It is interpreted as:

```
(select category,timefield from test where category='A'
 union
 select top 10 category,timefield from test where category='B'
)
order by timefield desc
```

(I'm not saying this is valid syntax.)

whereas what you want is:

```
(select category, timefield from test where category='A')
union
(select top 10 category, timefield from test where category='B' order by timefield desc)
```

Do note that `union` will remove duplicates.  If you don't want this additional overhead, use `union all` instead.

As to why this works as a subquery, my guess is that it is a coincidence.  SQL Server is not going to guarantee the results being returned when you use `top` without an `order by` -- or even that the results are consistent from one call to the next.  Sometimes it might actually do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that explains whats happening with my first statement but why does putting it into a subquery change the behaviour

Comment: @user1722957 . . . I don't think it does.  I think it is just a coincidence.

Comment: it's not a coincidence.

Comment: @ypercube - I think agree with you, can you explain why you think so. Just did some more tests and comparing the execution plans clearly shows that SQL treats the statement in the subQuery as a 'Top N Sort' operation.  I think it is evaluating the two statements very differently. It's not what you'd expect.

Comment: It's a SQL-Server quirk. Check: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/719420/unexpected-results-when-using-order-by-fetch-from-in-derived-tables-with-union

Comment: @ypercube - Excellent!  That's exactly whats going on.  So in short it is a known bug.  Can I award you points?

Comment: It's a known feature, according to Microsoft ;)